# SwiftUI: How to remove spacing between 2 sections? (iOS16)

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui

How to remove spacing between 2 sections.

[image]

This is my code

```swift
NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink( value: Color.mint) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "person").font(.system(size: 25)).padding(.trailing)
                            Text("Hi hello").font(.anuRegular(16))
                        }.frame(minHeight: 45)
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    NavigationLink( value: Color.mint) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "person").font(.system(size: 25)).padding(.trailing)
                            Text("Hi hello").font(.anuRegular(16))
                        }.frame(minHeight: 45)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
               
            }
            .navigationTitle("Categories")
        }
```

I've tried this method below from other stacks, but it doesn't work

```swift
init() {
           UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `list style` but then you will have to style the section cell yourself.

These two style will get rid of the space, see [here for a detailed explanation about list styles](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/swiftui-listview-part3/)

- `.listStyle(.inset)`
- `.listStyle(.plain)`

Comment: These styles wont remove the section spaces. May be the API has changed by now.